# Android: How do we get BiometricPrompt working with Samsung s10 (ultrasonic fingeprint scanner)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, androidx, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Has anyone gotten AndroidX BiometricPrompt to work with Samsung s10? (Model # SM-G973U1)

I'm getting Error code 11 with a blankerror string (after. authenticate) and the user does not see the prompt at all.

- See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142520323 (it has been assigned to someone..)
- Does it work for anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. A workaround has been implemented for rc02, which is being released on October23.